# PHP Understanding stream_get_contents on existing file opened with w+

Tags: php, file-pointer

I was trying to figure out file pointers in PHP, so I wrote a small script to test it out:

```
$fp = fopen('test.me', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, '12345');
rewind($fp);
echo 'contents: ['.stream_get_contents($fp)."]\n";
fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite($fp, '6789');
fclose($fp);
echo 'contents: ['.file_get_contents('test.me')."]\n";
```

Nice and easy. Open a file to read/write from it. Write to it. Go back to the beginning of the file, print out its contents. Go to the end of the file, append some more to it. Finally, print out the entire contents of the file.

I run it and get the exact results that I expect:

```
contents: [12345]
contents: [123456789]
```

Being so proud of myself for writing this masterpiece, I go to my terminal and hit up and enter to run it again.

This time:

```
contents: []
contents: [123456789]
```

Turns out that if the file exists at the start of the script, the first block is always `contents:[]`. If I delete the `test.me` file, then the first block is `contents:[12345]`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Doesn't seem like normal behavior so that's a good question.  Unable to reproduce on my system using PHP 5.6 / PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu.  Works as expected regardless of file existing prior to runtime.

Comment: That's my exact system this is running on as well...

Comment: Tested this on 2 different Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant machines, one running 5.6, the other running 7.0. Getting the same results on both.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm running 16.04, but not vagrant, but I doubt this comes down to Ubuntu version.   Possibly an issue with Vagrant?